# Menu Selection WIndow Creation for LCDsheild and arduino Interface

Tags: c, arduino, avr, lcd

I am trying to create Menu Selection process.if SELECT button pressed once should display the Display parameter and if select button pressed twice should goes to Set_parameter window(Where we set parameter). once it is display parameter using up and down arrow Choose the Display window .But problem i am facing here is It enter the Display parameter but comes out Menu window directly .

[Circuit diagram for LCD is given here](http://www.freetronics.com/pages/16x2-lcd-shield-quickstart-guide#.Uv9jb87pegI)

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
// Pin configuration of the buttons
#define btnRIGHT  0     // Okay
#define btnUP     1     // inc
#define btnDOWN   2     // dec
#define btnLEFT   3     // Select
#define btnSELECT 4     // Menu
#define btnNONE   5
#define beeper A1      // Alarm buzzer
#define shortBeep 100
#define longBeep  500
int button_counter=0;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
    Select_Menu();
}
void Select_Menu()
{
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("MENU");
 int button=read_LCD_buttons();
 if(button==btnSELECT)
 {
    button_counter=button_counter+1
 }
 if(button_counter==1)
 {
     Display_function();
 }else if((button_counter==2))
 {
    Set_function();
 }else
 {
    button_counter=0;
 }
}

void Display_function()
{
    int button = read_LCD_buttons();  
    if(button==btnUP)
    {
        button_counter=button_counter+1; 
        Serial.print("button_counter");
        Serial.println(button_counter);
    }else if(button==btnDOWN)
    {
        button_counter=button_counter-1; 
        Serial.println(button_counter);
    }
    if (button_counter>5)
    {
        button_counter=1;
    }else
        while(button_counter<5)
        {
            int button = read_LCD_buttons();  
            if(button != prev_button && button !=  btnNONE)
            {
                prev_button = button; 
            //timedBeep(shortBeep,2); 
            }

            if ((((button ==btnUP )||(button_counter==1))||((button ==btnDOWN )))&&(prev_button==btnUP)
            {
                digitalClockDisplay();//timedBeep(200,1); 

            }else if((((button ==btnUP )||(button_counter==2))||((button ==btnDOWN )))&&(prev_button==btnUP))
            {
                Display_angle();//timedBeep(200,1); 
            }else if((((button ==btnUP )||(button_counter==3))||((button ==btnDOWN )))&&(prev_button==btnUP))
            {
                Display_coordinate();//timedBeep(200,1); 
            }else if((((button ==btnUP )||(button_counter==4))||((button ==btnDOWN )))&&(prev_button==btnUP))
            {
                 button_loop();//timedBeep(500,4); 
            }else if((((button ==btnUP )||(button_counter==5))||((button ==btnDOWN )))&&(prev_button==btnUP))
            {
                  Display_Wind();//timedBeep(200,1); 
            }

        }
}


void Display_Wind()
{
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("WS kmph:");
 lcd.print(Wind_Kmph);
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);  
 lcd.print("WS m/s:");
 lcd.print(Wind_Speed);
}
void button_loop()
{
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("Welcome");
}
void Display_coordinate()
{
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("Latitude:");
 lcd.print(latitude);
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);  
 lcd.print("Longitude:");
 lcd.print(longitude);
}
void  Display_angle()
{
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("DESIRED: ");
 lcd.print(tracker_des_angle,DEC);
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("ACTUAL: ");
 lcd.print(tracker_actual_pos,DEC);

}
void digitalClockDisplay()
{
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("Date:");
 lcd.print(local_day);
 lcd.print("/");
 lcd.print(local_month);
 lcd.print("/");
 lcd.print(local_year);
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("Time:");
 lcd.print(local_h);
 lcd.print(":");
 lcd.print(local_m);
 lcd.print(":");
 lcd.print(local_s);
 lcd.print("   ");
}
int read_LCD_buttons()
{
  adc_key_in = analogRead(0);      // read the value from the sensor
  // my buttons when read are centered at these valies: 0, 131, 307, 481, 722
  // we add approx 50 to those values and check to see if we are close
  // No button pressed should be 1023
  if (adc_key_in > 1000) return btnNONE; // We make this the 1st option for speed reasons since it will be the most likely result
  if (adc_key_in < 50)   return btnRIGHT; 
  if (adc_key_in < 195)  return btnUP;
  if (adc_key_in < 380)  return btnDOWN;
  if (adc_key_in < 555)  return btnLEFT;
  if (adc_key_in < 790)  return btnSELECT;  
  return btnNONE;  // when all others fail, return this...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a flow control problem.

Your main loop runs `SelectMenu()` in there you enter `Display_function()` which contains no loop so it reaches the end and returns to `SelectMenu()` which then returns to `loop()` which again calls `SelectMenu()` redrawing your menu and overwriting the display with the menu again.

There are many ways to solve this, but as this is an arduino environment where resources are anything other than endless I would suggest you make each "page" its own loop breaking out of it when needing to move on. Do not switch pages inside the loops or you will build up quite the callstack.

Pseudo code:

```
loop():
  #print and handle input
  if (navigate)
    Display_function()

Display_function():
  while(true)
    # print and do whatever
    if (nav_angle)
       Display_angle()
    else if (nav_coord)
       Display_coordinate()
    #... etc.
    if (nav_back)
      return

Display_angle():
  while(true)
    #do stuff
    if (nav_back)
      return
```

This should give you the idea, it will work as long as you don't have too deep of a structure and run out of memory.

Comment: Can suggest Simple way of doing it.simple algorithm that avoid above issue.